# Не подключается к БД (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
try {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chat';
    $username = 'chat';
    $password = '1234';
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND = > 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Такая ошибка:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'chat'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: а вы пробовали к базе этим пользователем подключаться через консоль или через какого то мускульного клиента? может проблема отсутсвии базы/пользователя/прав?

Comment: @totorro Проблема в том, что пользователь с таким логином есть, и у него стоят все права.

Comment: повторюсь, Вы пробовали подключаться из других источников? кроме того какой пользователь есть?  'chat'@'localhost' или  'chat'@'*'?

Comment: @totorro Вхожу через pma

Comment: что показывают команды: `mysql>use mysql;` `mysql>select user from user;` И еще, вы скрипт запускаете на той же машине что и база находится?

Comment: @pride, "_Проблема в том, что пользователь с таким логином есть, и у него стоят все права._" значит либо пароль не верный либо вы ошибаетесь. MySQL вам однозначно дает понять, что доступа у этого пользователя нет. Вероятные причины: нет пользователя (**totorro** вам правильно указывает на хост пользователя), нет полномочий, неверный пароль.

Answer (score 2):

Одним из самых необходимых для программиста качеств является **способость верить своим глазам.** Не воображению, а объективной реальности, данной нам в ощущениях.

В данном случае - сообщению об ошибке. В котором недвусмысленно написано, что у пользователя chat отсутствуют права на подключение а БД. Либо потому что такого пользователя в БД нет, либо потому что указан неверный пароль.

Поняв и поверив сообщению об ошибке, следует приступать к ее исправлению. а именно - проверке логина и пароля из консоли.

В качестве бонса приведу **правильный** вариант кода соединения. Это не имеет отношения к проблеме неверного пароля, но зато исправляет много других проблем.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chat;charset=utf8';
$username = 'chat';
$password = '1234';
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
); 
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего Вы запускаете скрипт не на той же машине на которой находиться ваша БД. Ваш пользователь создан как пользователь который может авторизоваться в базе только с той машини на которой база запущена. Об этом говорит надпись `localhost` после `@` в имени пользователя `'chat'@'localhost'`.

Для того чтобы иметь возможность подключаться из сети к базе(читай запускать скрипт откуда угодно) нужно создать нового пользователя(если такового нет)

```
CREATE USER 'chat'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON chat.* TO 'chat'@'localhost';
```